# rsync from macOS to azure vm linux

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, remote

Im trying to rsync a big json file from my local machine to an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I keep getting the following error at the end of the process. The error is generated after the transfer is complete. I have ssh certificates set up and Im able to get into the vm ok. Any idea what Im missing here? Thanks for any guidance.

Command:

```
rsync -ahzP --progress --delete --inplace --verbose /Users/klik/Projects/sampledata/sample.json myvm@11.11.111.11:/
```

Error:

```
building file list ...
1 file to consider
sample.json
      77.25M 100%  397.06kB/s    0:03:09 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)
rsync: open "/sample.json" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 10.29M bytes  received 42 bytes  44.46K bytes/sec
total size is 77.25M  speedup is 7.51    
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myvm` user does not have permissions to write to `/` to create `sample.json` there. You either need to use the root user or change the permissions on `/` to allow others to write to it, if that's what you want to do.

If you wanted to put the file into `myvm`'s home directory instead, use just `myvm@11.11.111.11:` (no `/`).

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I thought, '/' was the home directory. how would i use the root user on the /newdir path from an rsync command. If i was in the vm I would run sudo but this rsync is being run from my local host. New to linux...

Comment: `root@11.11.111.11:/`

Comment: On azure linux root is disabled by default. Running with the created admin user still gets permission denied. You cant call sudo in the rsync command, can you?